# VBScript ADODB.Stream type mismatch

Tags: vbscript, binary, wmi, adodb

I am writing an HTA application to manage Hyper-V, and I am stuck on the GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage script. I took the VBScript example from:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160707(v=vs.85).aspx 
but that script never actually calls the sub to write the image file. I tried calling the SaveThumbnailImage sub with the arguments being (objOutParams.ImageData), and I get a "Type Mismatch" error on the stream.WriteText line 81. For some reason, the ADODB is rejecting the binary data? I would appreciate any help with this.

```
option explicit 

dim objWMIService
dim managementService
dim fileSystem

const wmiStarted = 4096
const wmiSuccessful = 0

Main()


'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Main
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Main()

    dim computer, objArgs, strArgs, vmName, vm

    set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
    if WScript.Arguments.Count = 1 then
        computer = Split(objArgs.Unnamed.Item(0),",")(0)
        vmName = Split(objArgs.Unnamed.Item(0),",")(1)
    else
        WScript.Echo "usage: cscript GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage.vbs hostName,vmName"
        WScript.Quit(1)
    end if

    set fileSystem = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & computer & "\root\virtualization\v2")
    set managementService = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService").ItemIndex(0)

    set vm = GetComputerSystem(vmName)

    if StartVm(vm) then
        if GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage(vm) then
            WriteLog "Done"
            WScript.Quit(0)
         End if
    end if

    WriteLog "GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage Failed."
    WScript.Quit(1)

End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Retrieve Msvm_VirtualComputerSystem from base on its ElementName
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetComputerSystem(vmElementName)
'   On Error Resume Next
    dim query
    query = Format1("select * from Msvm_ComputerSystem where ElementName = '{0}'", vmElementName)
    set GetComputerSystem = objWMIService.ExecQuery(query).ItemIndex(0)
    if (Err.Number <> 0) then
        WriteLog Format1("Err.Number: {0}", Err.Number)
        WriteLog Format1("Err.Description:{0}",Err.Description)
        WScript.Quit(1)
    end if
End Function

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Save the thumbnail
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub SaveThumbnailImage(thumbnailBytes)

    dim stream 
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2  

    set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stream.Type = adTypeText

    stream.Open
    Redim text(ubound(thumbnailBytes) \ 2)
    Dim i
    for i = lbound(thumbnailBytes) to ubound(thumbnailBytes) step 2
        text(i\2) = ChrW(thumbnailBytes(i + 1) * &HFF + thumbnailBytes(i))
    next
    stream.WriteText text

    stream.SaveToFile ".\thumbnail.png", adSaveCreateOverWrite
    stream.Close


End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Start the virtual machine 
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function StartVm(computerSystem)

    dim objInParam, objOutParams
    StartVm = false
    if computerSystem.OperationalStatus(0) = 2 then
        StartVm = true
        Exit Function
    end if

    set objInParam = computerSystem.Methods_("RequestStateChange").InParameters.SpawnInstance_()
    objInParam.RequestedState = 2
    set objOutParams = computerSystem.ExecMethod_("RequestStateChange", objInParam)

    if objOutParams.ReturnValue = wmiStarted then
        if (WMIJobCompleted(objOutParams)) then
            StartVm = true
        end if
    elseif objOutParams.ReturnValue = wmiSuccessful then
        StartVm = true
    else
        WriteLog Format1("StartVM failed with ReturnValue {0}", wmiStatus)
    end if

End Function


'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Print the thumbnail data
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub PrintThumbnailImage(thumbnailBytes)
    dim index
    dim i
    for index = lbound(thumbnailBytes) to ubound(thumbnailBytes)
        WriteLog Format2("{0}:{1} ", index, thumbnailBytes(i))
    next
End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Define a virtual system
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage(computerSystem)
    dim query, objInParam, objOutParams, virtualSystemsetting

    GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage = false

    query = Format1("ASSOCIATORS OF {{0}} WHERE resultClass = Msvm_VirtualSystemsettingData", computerSystem.Path_.Path)
    set virtualSystemsetting = objWMIService.ExecQuery(query).ItemIndex(0)

    set objInParam = managementService.Methods_("GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage").InParameters.SpawnInstance_()

    objInParam.HeightPixels = 150
    objInParam.WidthPixels = 100
    objInParam.TargetSystem = virtualSystemsetting.Path_.Path

    set objOutParams = managementService.ExecMethod_("GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage", objInParam)

    if objOutParams.ReturnValue = wmiStarted then
        if (WMIJobCompleted(objOutParams)) then
            GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage = true
        end if
    elseif objOutParams.ReturnValue = wmiSuccessful then
        Dim strData : strData = objOutParams.ImageData
        SaveThumbnailImage(strData)
'       PrintThumbnailImage(strData)
        GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage = true
    else
        WriteLog Format1("GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage failed with ReturnValue {0}", wmiStatus)
    end if

End Function


'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Handle wmi Job object
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function WMIJobCompleted(outParam)

    dim WMIJob, jobState

    set WMIJob = objWMIService.Get(outParam.Job)

    WMIJobCompleted = true

    jobState = WMIJob.JobState

    while jobState = JobRunning or jobState = JobStarting
        WriteLog Format1("In progress... {0}% completed.",WMIJob.PercentComplete)
        WScript.Sleep(1000)
        set WMIJob = objWMIService.Get(outParam.Job)
        jobState = WMIJob.JobState
    wend

    if (jobState <> JobCompleted) then
        WriteLog Format1("ErrorCode:{0}", WMIJob.ErrorCode)
        WriteLog Format1("ErrorDescription:{0}", WMIJob.ErrorDescription)
        WMIJobCompleted = false
    end if

End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
' Create the console log files.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
Sub WriteLog(line)
    dim fileStream
    set fileStream = fileSystem.OpenTextFile(".\GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage.log", 8, true)
'   WScript.Echo line
    fileStream.WriteLine line
    fileStream.Close

End Sub


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' The string formatting functions to avoid string concatenation.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Format2(myString, arg0, arg1)
    Format2 = Format1(myString, arg0)
    Format2 = Replace(Format2, "{1}", arg1)
End Function


'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' The string formatting functions to avoid string concatenation.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Format1(myString, arg0)
    Format1 = Replace(myString, "{0}", arg0)
End Function
```

Comment: I have no way to test it, but, as `text` is an array, can you try with `stream.WriteText join(text,"")`?

Comment: Have you tried using `stream.Type = adTypeBinary` and `stream.write text`? I mean, you are writing binary data.